# How to create an MFC MDI application with a tabbed interface using visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Any reference to a nice tutorial about how to create an MFC MDI application with a tabbed interface using visual studio 2010, my main point is to control there numbers etc properly through programming thanx in advance

Comment: You didn't google very hard: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982112(v=vs.100).aspx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one with the wizard after you have installed the latest service pack with the included Feature pack.

On the second page select type MDI with tabbed Interface. That is all.